# Error: Dependency is not satisfiable: libasound2 (>= 1.0.23) Wine

Tags: wine

I am trying to install **wine 1.4** on my **Ubuntu 10.04**. I downloaded the deb file from 
[Ubuntu Packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/otherosfs/wine1.4-i386)
I opened the file and I get this error

> Dependency is not satisfiable: libasound2 (>= 1.0.23)

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The installation depends on `libasound2` (>= 1.0.23)

you can download this package from the link below

For current versions of Ubuntu use [this link](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libasound2)...

after download install the `.deb` package using

```
sudo dpkg -i package.deb
```

Here package.deb will actually be the name of your downloaded package name.